# Adding Fields to a Meteor Cursor

Tags: javascript, meteor

How can I iterate over a cursor and add a field to each document? Something like this, which doesn't seem to work:

```
function getNewItems() {
    var items = Items.find();
    items.forEach(function(item) {
        item.newField = true;
    });
    return items;
}
```

I want to modify the documents in Iron Router's `data` function before sending it to the template.

Comment: Could you instead just use a [template helper](http://docs.meteor.com/#template_helpers) within an `#each` block that computes the value you want from `this`?

Comment: Sorry, my question probably wasn't clear enough. Yes, I've been thinking about this the wrong way. It would be simpler to use a template helper. What I want to do is add an extra field specific to the user, just for display, which doesn't need to be stored in the database. However, I'd still like to know how to do this outside of an `each` block.

Comment: I'm confused. An `each` block is just how to iterate over a cursor for display, and a template helper invoked as ``{{newField}}`` within the block would effectively add a display-only "field" to the document, where the helper map item is e.g. `newField: function () return Meteor.user().profile.name + this.existingField;` or whatever, and that still seems to me to be what you want.

Comment: Yes. But I don't understand how I would do the same thing if I needed to use the field for other purposes, and couldn't do it within the template. Like if I needed to do the same thing on the server.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Depending on your exact requirement -

if you want to compute a value on each item, just for display purposes (eg fields to use in the template):

```
Items.find({ /* selector */ }, {
   transform: function(item){
      item.newField = true;
      return item;
    }
});
```

But, if you would like to update every document with different values (in mongodb), using the Meteor api's:

```
var items = Items.find({ /* selector */});
items.forEach(function(item){
   var someValue = computeSomeValue(item);
   Items.update({
     _id: item._id
   }, {
      $set: {
         newField: someValue
      }
   });
 });
```

otherwise, if you just want to update every matchhed item with the SAME value:

```
Items.update({ /* selector */}, {
  $set: {
    newField: true
    },
  },
  { 
    multi: true
  }
);
```

If you're doing this client-side in Meteor- your success (on the last two options) will also depend on using the `insecure` package or setting correct `allow` or `deny` rules on the `Items` collection.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need to maintain the cursor abstraction and can just return an Array:

```
function getNewItems() {
  return Items.find().map(function(item) {
    return _.extend(item, {newField: true});
  });
}
```

If you insist on maintaining a cursor abstraction, you could handle `Items.find().observe` callbacks that maintain `newField` on a local collection (e.g. `NewItems = new Meteor.Collection(null)`) from which you would yield a cursor to a caller.

Answer (score 0):

To change the objects in local MongoDB cache, use MongoDB update operators: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/modify-documents/

Comment: When I try this on a cursor, I get the error "Object [object Object] has no method 'update'."

Comment: Right, because you do it on a collection, not on cursor

Comment: I don't want to update the collection, just the cursor.

Comment: I don't understand what does the "update cursor" mean. maybe you should take a step back and try a different approach.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the different answers, there are other ways to reach your goal there, but if you strictly must iterate over your cursor with forEach, then you must know that once a cursor is iterated manually within forEach, map, or fetch, it must be rewinded as [per the docs](http://docs.meteor.com/#rewind) state.

Please see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21887442/1064151) to a very similar problem.

```
function getNewItems() {
    var items = Items.find();
    items.forEach(function(item) {
        item.newField = true;
    });

    items.rewind(); // See how I reset the cursor to its initial position here

    return items;
}
```

Comment: If I run this code:
    `var items = Items.find();
    items.forEach(function(item) {
     item.newField = 'test';
    });
    items.rewind();
    items.forEach(function(item) {
     console.log(item.newField);
    });`
I get undefined every time.

Comment: oh yes, you're right, since you rewind the cursor, you lose the modifications.